# Spring form tag creates array of values

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, data-binding, spring-form

I have simple form where user can choose a value from select. I am not sure how it works but if there are the selects pointing to the same filed in POJO class value is not overridden but two values are separated by comma. Why this is happening? Is there any String concatenation behid the scenes?

It looks like this:

```
<form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="student">

        First Name : <form:input path="firstName"/>
        <br><br>
        Last Name : <form:input path="lastName"/>
        <br><br>
        Country : <form:select path="country">
                    <form:option value="Brazil" label="Brazil" />
                    <form:option value="France" label="France" />
                    <form:option value="Germany" label="Germany"></form:option>
                    <form:option value="India" label="India"></form:option>
                    <form:option value="" label="Select" />
                </form:select>
        <br><br>
        Country : <form:select path="country">
                    <form:options items="${student.countryOptions}" />
                </form:select>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form:form>
```

[image]

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

    @Value("#{countryOptionsID}")
    private Map<String, String> countryOptionsProperties;

    @Value("#{favoriteLanguageID}")
    private Map<String, String> favoriteLanguageProperties;

    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Model theModel) {

        theModel.addAttribute("student", new Student());
        // add the country options to the model
        theModel.addAttribute("theCountryOptions", countryOptionsProperties);
        theModel.addAttribute("theFavoriteLanguageOptions", favoriteLanguageProperties);
        return "student-form";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("student") Student theStudent) {
        System.out.println("Student Details : " + theStudent);
        return "student-confirmation";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processFormA")
    public String processFormA(Student student) { //without using @ModelAttribute
        System.out.println("without using @ModelAttribute Student Details : " + student);
        return "student-confirmation";
    }

}
```

and properties are like:

```
BR=Brazil
FR=France
CO=Colombia
IN=India
LK=Sri Lanka
```

Comment: it seems that you do smth wrong in the controller. Could you show your code of controller?

Comment: hey, I've edited the  code please take a look :)

Comment: How you construct your `Student` object? there is a `countryOptions` field that is a key.

Comment: what about now? Everything is fine with the controller and its methods. My question is why data binding performed on one filed from POJO merges two string into one and separate this with comma

Answer (score 0):

If you fill out the model in the controller:

```
theModel.addAttribute("theCountryOptions", countryOptionsProperties);
```

It means that in the view you could get this object:

```
Country : 
<form:select path="country">
    <form:options items="${theCountryOptions}" />
</form:select>
```

Comment: @Mateusz Gebroski if this answer helps you, please, accept it. Otherwise ask me to clarify and provide a link to the repo of your app or give more code